# Simple Servlet mapping

Tags: java, spring, servlets, spring-mvc

I am trying to implement Spring onto a small app.
I am getting the following:

```
WARNING: No mapping found for HTTP request with URI [/audiClave/] in DispatcherServlet with name 'appServlet'
```

Here is my web.xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
    xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" 
    xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd" 
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee
    http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd" 
    id="WebApp_ID" 
    version="3.0">
    <display-name>audiClave</display-name>
<!-- Processes application requests -->
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>appServlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-                            class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>/WEB-INF/spring/appServlet/servlet-context.xml</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>      

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>appServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

And here is the servlet-context.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
xsi:schemaLocation="
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-3.0.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd">

<!-- DispatcherServlet Context: defines this servlet's request-processing infrastructure -->

<!-- Scans within the base package of the application for @Components to configure as beans -->
<!-- @Controller, @Service, @Configuration, etc. -->
<context:component-scan base-package="com.audiClave.Service" />

<!-- Enables the Spring MVC @Controller programming model -->
<mvc:annotation-driven />

</beans>
```

The controller is:

```
package com.audiClave.Service;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;

/**
 * Handles requests for the application home page.
 */
@Controller
public class HomeController {

@RequestMapping(value = "/")
public String home() {
    System.out.println("HomeController: Passing through...");
    return "WEB-INF/views/home.jsp";
}
}
```

http://localhost:8080/audiClave/ returns:

```
HTTP Status 404
The requested resource () is not available.
```

I am running under eclipse using tomcat 7.0.12 and spring 3.0.5. The content appears to be correctly deployed to E:\development\java.metadata.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp0\wtpwebapps\audiClave

When I changed the mapping to /* it was able to find the controller, but then the home.jsp doesn't work because the wild card matches it as well

RESOLVED when I took the /* out of the mapping again.
Thanks

Comment: is your application deployed in "webapps/audiClave" ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do just `return "home"` (instead of the whole path to the jsp). The View handler should be configured to look for the views in that folder, with that extension.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response but it doesn't seem to have helped. I am still getting 26/05/2011 10:15:08 PM org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet noHandlerFound
WARNING: No mapping found for HTTP request with URI [/audiClave/] in DispatcherServlet with name 'appServlet'
I don't think it is finding the home() method at all

Comment: I updated to 3.0.5 but it didn't help.
When I changed the mapping to <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern> it was able to find the controller, but then the home.jsp doesn't work because the wild card matches it as well.

Comment: there was an issue with tomcat pre-7.0.5. Which tomcat are you using exactly?

Answer (score 0):

The problem should be this:
In file [filename]-servlet.xml please enter the following line:
`< mvc:resources location="/index.html" mapping="/index.html" />`